# Multipolygon to single polygon

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, c#, sharpmap, dotspatial

I am trying to merge the three polygon to make a single Polygon. The WKT of the polygon is as below

```
//TMP_6
POLYGON ((626480.63252975536 3069129.8280593003, 626489.846006365 3069133.60864098, 626490.11177066388 3069130.4749546046, 626480.8982940542 3069126.694372925, 626480.63252975536 3069129.8280593003))

//TMP_2
POLYGON ((626488.9601253689 3069144.0542622306, 626489.31011962891 3069144.1978759766, 626494.41571044922 3069144.2816772461, 626496.06872558594 3069143.8421020508, 626498.47509765625 3069142.75390625, 626499.68890380859 3069140.8081054688, 626500.00012207043 3069140.3687133789, 626500.00012207043 3069134.3719907566, 626489.79547264136 3069134.2044954351, 626488.9601253689 3069144.0542622306))

//TMP_3
POLYGON ((626500.00012207043 3069134.3719907566, 626500.00012207043 3069122.3228759766, 626498.07330322266 3069121.9630737305, 626496.90808105469 3069121.7133178711, 626492.96392822266 3069117.9188842773, 626492.49792480469 3069117.4194946289, 626491.30769381113 3069116.3735569054, 626489.79547264136 3069134.2044954351, 626500.00012207043 3069134.3719907566))
```

I am using `IGeometry.Union(IGeometry)` method to merge these three into single. But the result is unexpected. I got a MULTIPOLYGON with following WKT.

```
//Merged Result is MultiPolygon
MULTIPOLYGON (((626480.63252975536 3069129.8280593003, 626489.846006365 3069133.60864098, 626490.11177066388 3069130.4749546046, 626480.8982940542 3069126.694372925, 626480.63252975536 3069129.8280593003)), ((626488.9601253689 3069144.0542622306, 626489.31011962891 3069144.1978759766, 626494.41571044922 3069144.2816772461, 626496.06872558594 3069143.8421020508, 626498.47509765625 3069142.75390625, 626499.68890380859 3069140.8081054688, 626500.00012207043 3069140.3687133789, 626500.00012207043 3069134.3719907566, 626500.00012207043 3069122.3228759766, 626498.07330322266 3069121.9630737305, 626496.90808105469 3069121.7133178711, 626492.96392822266 3069117.9188842773, 626492.49792480469 3069117.4194946289, 626491.30769381113 3069116.3735569054, 626489.79547264136 3069134.2044954351, 626488.9601253689 3069144.0542622306)))
```

In Visual it looks like below
[image]

Now How can I get the Combined Polygon in the form of the `IGeometry`?

Answer (score 3):

If you zoom close enough you will see that the polygon on the left does not match with the border of the polygon on the right.

[image]

To make them match add new verticis to the right side polygon at the connection points and snap them to correcponding vertices of the left side polygon. It is possible that polygons do share a common boundary but when the material vertices are missing QGIS must compute the points of intersection on-the-fly with the accuracy that is possible with double-precision floating-point numbers. In this case the result of the computation makes a gap between the polygons.

In this case increasing the source polygons with a buffer of 1 mm and shrinking the result by 1 mm should give one polygon. However, all the remaining vertices may not be the same that you had in the source polygons.